# Can't push docker image into private repository

Tags: docker, manjaro

I'm trying to push my image to my friend's private repository but I keep getting this error:

```
Index response didn't contain any endpoints
```

I have added --insecure-repository to my launch config because it didn't wanted to start at all.

I'm using the newest manjaro.

```
[jhajto@dev-station so_backend_old]$ docker info
Containers: 11
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 11
Images: 15
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 44
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.4.13-1-MANJARO
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.785 GiB
Name: dev-station
ID: CXRT:OQVN:F7O5:DNMU:FV2C:GZNE:KX6D:OINQ:SXLB:23HZ:NGBU:5WBC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

Comment: you'll probably get a better answer if you can provide some additional details here.  For example what's the exact command you're using to try and push the image to the repository?  Can you see the repository ok at a network level (e.g. ping the host and see the registry port)?

Answer (score 0):

It was DNS's fault, after specifying ip in /etc/hosts it works as a dream.